# ASP.NET MVC - Serializable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, serialization, serializable

I'm trying to use the new Html helper extension Serialize() from the furthure assembly..

If you take a look at:

View

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<MvcApplication2.Models.ProductViewBinding>>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc" %>>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products", FormMethod.Post))
       { %>
       <% int codeIndex = 0;
           foreach (var item in Model)
          { %>
          <%: Html.TextBox("Encryption[" + codeIndex + "].Value") %>
          <%: Html.Serialize("Encryption[" + codeIndex + "].ID", item.ID) %>
          <% codeIndex++; 
        } %>
       <%: Html.SubmitButton("Click meh!") %>
    <% } %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Model

```
[Serializable] 
public class ProductViewBinding
{

    public object ID { get; set; }

    [NonSerialized]
    public object _value;
    public object Value 
    { 
        get { return this._value; } 
        set { this._value = value; } 
    }

}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Deserialize] List<ProductViewBinding> Encryption)
{
    return View("Index", Encryption);
}
```

It returns null when posted... but if I remove the [Deserialize] attribute it returns as it should but with the ID still encrypted... Any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing the point of how the `Serialize` helper is supposed to work. You pass it an entire object graph which is serialized and stored in a hidden field that you could get back in a controller action using the `[Deserialize]` attribute. You cannot have half of your object serialized and the other half not.

---

UPDATE:

After seeing your comment here's a workaround:

Model:

```
public class ProductViewBinding
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new[] 
        {
            new ProductViewBinding { ID = "1", Value = "value 1" }, 
            new ProductViewBinding { ID = "2", Value = "value 2" }, 
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(
        [Deserialize(SerializationMode.Encrypted)]string[] ids,
        string[] values
    )
    {
        IEnumerable<ProductViewBinding> model = values.Zip(
            ids, (id, value) => new ProductViewBinding { ID = id, Value = value }
        );
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SomeNs.Models.ProductViewBinding[]>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%: Html.Serialize("ids", Model.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray(), SerializationMode.Encrypted) %>
        <%for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++) { %>
            <%: Html.TextBox("Values[" + i + "]", Model[i].Value) %>
        <% } %>
        <%: Html.SubmitButton("Click meh!") %>
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the `SerializationMode.Encrypted` flag which is used if you want to achieve encryption, otherwise the user can tamper with the values.

Comment: I see.. But what would be the right way to Encrypt a key into a hidden field thats used to identifie the textbox when its a List<>? The thing I was trying to do would be ideal if it worked.. because I only need the ID field to be serialized, not the textbox (Value)...

Comment: Works great! - However users can still tamper with the values?

Comment: No, they can't tamper with the IDS because they are encrypted. If someone tampers with the values you will get either null in the controller action or exception but a user won't be able to modify a value.

Comment: If I edit the value of the generated hidden field for "ids" it returns "invalid length for a base-64 char array", and if I just copy another Serialize field' value to the "ids" value then it's accepted?

Comment: I have 2 Html.Serialize() on my site.. both are defined as strings... public ActionResult Order([Deserialize(SerializationMode.EncryptedAndSigned)] string[] ids,[Deserialize(SerializationMode.EncryptedAndSigned)] string[] pnames, string[] values) - So if I take the value from "pnames" and give it to "ids" it accepted.. - Would it be best to try to combine them into one to avoid such a thing?

Comment: Yes you should combine them into one.

Comment: I have just noticed a problem of same kind.. I have 2 pages -> Order(enter personal info etc.) and a confirm page. If I copy the value in the serialized hidden field from the Order page to Confirm page' hidden field, its accepted?