# Simplest way to add a hidden field for all properties of a Asp.net MVC 3 model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need pass through all values of model to the next controller. I could create hidden fields for all properties of the model, but this is always a bit error prone when the model gets new fields.

I tried this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x)
```

but that just leads to the error

```
CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
```

(I don't like using Tempdata because its so short lived, and unplaned page reloads)
Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Check [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3633505/60108)

Comment: that could work, but is also a bit clunky ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the property you are using in the lambda experssion

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Username)
```

Comment: that just adds a single property from the model. I would like to add the whole model in one go.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just pull it from the database?  If the user can't change the values then why do you need to send it back and forth?  A malicious user can modify the hidden field value and try to post it back to the server.  Pulling from the database would be faster and more secure.